How does $|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$? If I use algebra and break it down I just get to $1=-1$.
I have gotten to a chapter in my pre-calculus textbook where it mentions this equation: $|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$
It doesn't really explain why that equation is true, and it just sort of moves on afterwards. This made no sense to me but normally when I can't figure something out I can just break it down and it just works because its math and math is consistent so that generally resolves the issue. In this case, it has just made me incredibly confused.
To my understanding, absolute value takes a number and leaves it unchanged if it is positive and turns it into a positive number if it is negative. It then stands to reason that the only $2$ possible options are that $|a|=a$ or $|a|=(-a)$. If I apply that logic to this equation, then I get this.
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+bi \text{ or } \sqrt{a^2+b^2}=-(a+bi)\\\implies
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+bi\text{ or }\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=-a-bi\\\implies\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a=bi \text{ or } \sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a=-bi\\\implies{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a\over b}=i \text{ or } {\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a\over-b}=i\implies \sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a=-(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a)\implies\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a=-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a\implies 1 =-1\text{?}$$
$1$ obviously does not equal $-1$ so what is going on here? So far the answers I have gotten are "$i$ doesn't work like that because its a nonreal number" which makes no sense at all given that regardless of whether or not it is real, it is still a constant so it should be subject to things like the transitive law, and "that's not supposed to be absolute value its a different thing called modulus" but from googling it seems like those are the exact same in this context. The only options I can think of are
$\boldsymbol{1)}$ I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how absolute value works (I don't think it's this because I have seen absolute value used like this when dealing with quadratic equations)
$\boldsymbol{2)}$ There is some other issue with this math (I don't think it's this because I have gone over it more than I can count)
$\boldsymbol{3)}$ This equation is incorrect (I don't think it's this because both my pre-calculus teacher and math book disagree with this and there is literally an entire chapter dedicated to complex numbers and this equation)
Currently the option I am leaning towards is option #3 because I know that less advanced math curriculums will oversimplify things sometimes to the point of just being incorrect, but this is pre-calculus. I feel like I would have gotten past that sort of thing.

$|z|=1$ does not imply that $z$ is $1$ or $-1$.

Then what does $|z|$ mean? What other number could $|z|$ equal other than $1$ or $-1$?

You have to take a book on Complex Analysis and learn the basics. Complex numbers do not work like real numbers.

$| i |=1$, but $i$ is not equal to +1 or -1.

Your mistake is that you consider the modulus of a complex number to be the same as the modulus of a real number. If you want a general definition, then the modulus for both is the distance to the origin. Therefore, the formulas, in general, are different for a straight line, real numbers, and a plane, complex numbers.

In that case why a second dimension specifically for $i$?

$i$ shows you which one is second dimension: number $a+ib$ is point $(a,b)$ on plane. If you have single $i$, then $i=0+i\cdot 1$ i.e. we have point $(0,1)$ on plane.

But why add a second dimension for complex numbers?

Complex numbers by definition are points of plane i.e. pairs.

But what about multiplying a number by $i$ makes it necessary to switch from 1 dimension to 2?

"absolute value takes a number and leaves it unchanged if it is positive and turns it into a positive number if it is negative." that's only true for real numbers where all non-zero numbers are either negative or positive and those are the only options. In complex numbers that is not the case. "It then stands to reason that the only 2 possible options are that |a|=a or |a|=(−a)" No.  It doesn't stand to reason.  It stands to reason that there is only one "size" but you have two dimensions so you have an entire circle of numbers that have that size. Not just two.

@Darkturtle999 The questions you are reckoning with are very deep; I would recommend reading the first section of the first chapter (the introduction) of Visual Complex Analysis. You can find it online as a PDF; it has a historical explanation and lots of pictures.

"But why add a second dimension for complex numbers?" One for the real direction, and one for the imaginary direction. "But what about multiplying a number by i makes it necessary to switch from 1 dimension to 2?"  Because $i$ is neither negative [ $(neg)\times (neg)=positive$ but $i \times i = neg$], nor positive [$(pos)\times (pos)=positive$ but $i\times i = neg$] and it's not zero.  So it has to exist in other direction than left (neg) or right (pos).  It must exist (up/imaginary) or (down/neg.imaginary)$

"It doesn't really explain why that equation is true"  That's a definition.  Definitions don't have reasons.  The are the reasons.  But.... since you ask.  $|  |$ is in essence a normed distance, how far a number is from the origin.  In one dimension, (pos/neg) the distance a number from $0$ is just how many units to the left or right.  But in complex we have two dimensions (pos/neg)$\times$(i/-i) and so distance is figured by the pythagorian theorem.

Your answer to "but why add a second dimension for complex numbers" is pretty much exactly what I was wondering, thank you. That actually makes a lot of sense.

It looks like the issue is that you are seeing $|a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ as a theorem to be proved. But that isn't what it is. It's the definition of what "$|\cdots|$" means when applied to complex numbers.

To my understanding, absolute value takes a number and leaves it unchanged if it is positive and turns it into a positive number if it is negative. It then stands to reason that the only 2 possible options are that $|a|=a$
or $|a|=(−a)$.

You're taking a something that you know about the real number definition and trying to generalize it to complex numbers. This is a great way of thinking, but it looks like you're learning that the property, "either $|a| = a$ or $|a| = -a$," doesn't work out so well for complex numbers. But that just means that it might be better to try to generalize some other property.
Well, we can also think as the absolute value as the distance from the origin. When you picture complex numbers as points on the complex plane, this naturally gives rise to the definition $|a + ib| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, as Masd pointed out.

One way to see if a generalization is "good" is to see if it preserves nice properties of the original definition. Real number absolute values satisfy these useful identities:
$$
|x + y| \leq |x| + |y|,\\
|xy| = |x||y|.
$$
And you can prove that the complex number definition satisfies these too.

There may be a lot of opinions on how to define the absolute value. But in general, when we define the absolute value, we calculate the distance between the point of the value and the point $O$, which has an all-zero value.
Therefore, we define the absolute value of a complex number as the distance between the point $O$ and the point of the complex number on a complex plane.
For example, when we calculate $|3+4i|$, we think about the point $(3, 4)$ and $(0, 0)$, then calculate the distance of two points, which can be calculated as $\sqrt{(3-0)^2+(4-0)^2}=5.$
In general, we can define the absolute value of $a+bi$(which is $|a+bi|$) as ${\mathbf{\sqrt{(a-0)^2+(b-0)^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}$.

Here's another way to think about it that I think helps. The regular absolute value you know applies only to real numbers. As soon as we start adding on complex numbers, we have to do something to extend that absolute value to complex numbers.
So what are our choices? Interestingly, when we add $i$, we really can't distinguish it from $-i$ algebraically since both could be the root of $x^2+1$ we add to the real numbers. (In fact, any quadratic with negative discriminant can be used, we don't have to specifically add roots of $x^2+1$ to get complex numbers.)
What this means is if we want to be fair about it, $|a+bi|=|a-bi|$ should hold true since we can't really distinguish between them by algebra. Now if multiply that equation by $|a+bi|$ on both sides we get,
$$|a+bi|^2=|a+bi||a-bi|$$
And now let's make another choice, because we like that $|xy|=|x||y|$ for real numbers, let's say we want that to still be true for complex numbers and immediately use it to combine the right side together:
$$|a+bi|^2=|(a+bi)(a-bi)|$$
It turns out that this multiplies to make an entirely real, positive number. So we can evaluate this as if it were our old absolute value!
$$|a+bi|^2=|a^2+b^2|$$
$$|a+bi|^2=a^2+b^2$$
Square root both sides and we have discovered how to define our extension to complex numbers!
$$|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
We still have other properties we might like to check such as the triangle inequality, but we've kept ourselves to making reasonable choices along the way to arrive at our answer. (For what it's worth, the same line of thinking also holds true for extending a p-adic absolute value to a field extension as well.)
